# iBatis 3 - Collection with multiple column for join

Tags: java, join, ibatis

I have a little problem with iBatis 3 and its Collection statement.

For Example, I have a POJO called Boy with a property of List girlFriends;

A Boy may have more than one Girl.

Normally I use a resultMap with a collection statement like:

```
<collection property="girlFriends" column="idBoy" 
                     javaType="List" ofType="Girl"
                     select="package.GirlDao.loadGirlsByIdBoy" />
```

This statement works great by how can I do the same when load methos required more than one parameters used in Map?

Take this load method in GirlDao:

```
loadGirlByBoy(@Param("idBoy") Long idBoy, @Param("sex") String sex);
```

I have tried to do something like this (adding "sex" column to collection):

```
<collection property="girlFriends" column="idBoy,sex" 
                         javaType="List" ofType="Girl"
                         select="package.GirlDao.loadGirlsByBoy" />
```

but it doens't work.

How can I have a "join" with multiple parameters without having an object?

Thanks.